# Entry-types in alphadin

Tags: bibtex

Is there any documentation of the entry-types in `alphadin.bst`? If not, what's the easiest way to find out, which fields of a given entry-type are available, which are required, which optional and which are ignored?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the file by

```
kpsewhich alphadin.bst
```

which on this machine reports

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/din1505/alphadin.bst
```

looking at that file near the top is:

```
ENTRY
  { address      %%  Verlagsort (immer!)
    author       %%  persoenlicher Urheber eines Werkes oder am Zustandekommen
                 %%  beteiligte Personen(=Mitarbeiter, Uebersetzer, Redakteur u.a.)
    booktitle    %%  a) Gesamttitel eines mehrbaendigen Werkes
%                %%  b) Titel des Sammelwerks, das einzelne selbstaendige
%                %%     Beitraege mit eigenem Titel enthaelt ->incollection
    chapter      %%  Kapitel in einem Buch (Monographie)
    doi          %%% Digital Object Identifier ->article
    edition      %%  a) Auflagevermerk
%                %%  b) bei selbst. elektron. Quellen == Version ->booklet
    editor       %%  Persoenl.Herausgeber oder Koerperschaftlicher Herausgeber
    howpublished %%  beliebiger Verlegervermerk: veroeffentlicht "von wem, wo"
    institution  %%  Institution, die e.verlagsfreie Veroeffentlichung betreibt
    isbn         %%  Standardnr fuer Buecher
    issn         %%  - " -    :      Zeitschriften u. Serien
    journal      %%  Titel einer Zeitschrift
    key          %%  Zusaetzlich vergebener Sortierschluessel, mitunter notwend.
    lastchecked  %%  neues Feld fuer das Datum des Online-Abrufs
%                %%  einer Internetquelle (n. GRAY )
    month        %%  naehere Bestimmung des Erscheinungsjahres -> macro 's
    note         %%  freies Eingabefeld fuer zusaetzliche Informationen z. Quelle
    number       %%  Versch. Bedeutungen in Abhaengigkeit vom Eingabetyp:
%                %%  a) Bandnummer einer gezaehlten Reihe (series)
%                %%  b) Heftnummer einer Zeitschrift ->article
%                %%  c) Nummer eines Forschungsberichts ->techreport
    organization %%  a) Name der Organisation/des Organisators e. Tagung,Konferenz
%                %%  b) Name einer Firma/Gesellschaft, die ein ->manual herausgab
    pages        %%  Umfangsangaben, meist Seitenzahlen
    publisher    %%  Verlag
    school       %%  Hochschule/Universitaet, die eine Dipl.-Arb./Dissertation veroeff.
    series       %%  Titel e.Reihe, in der ein best. Buchtitel erschienen ist
    title        %%  Titel einer (namentlich gekennzeichneten) Veroeffentlichung
    type         %%  Zusatzfeld z.Kennzeichnung e.besonderen Publikationstyps
    url          %%  neues Feld URL ( Uniform Resource Locator ):
%                %%  Serveradresse einer Internetquelle
    urn          %%  neues Feld URN ( Uniform Resource Name ):
%                %%  Persistent Identifier einer Internetquelle
    volume       %%  a) Zaehlung bei einem mehrbaendigen Werk ->book/->proceedings
%                %%  b) Jahrgang einer Zeitschrift ->article
    year         %%  Erscheinungsjahr
```

which documents all the supported fields (I don't read German but the above is mostly understandable just by guessing what the long words mean:-)

To find the entry types look for FUNCTION lines where the function name doesn't have a dot

```
22 matches for "^FUNCTION[^.]*$" in buffer: alphadin.bst
    162:FUNCTION { eress } { "Elektronische Ressource" }
    252:FUNCTION {output}
    291:FUNCTION {not}
    308:FUNCTION {and}
    319:FUNCTION {or}
    409:FUNCTION {emphasize}
    424:FUNCTION { capitalize }
   1337:FUNCTION {article}
   1361:FUNCTION {book}
   1395:FUNCTION {booklet}
   1427:FUNCTION {inbook}
   1456:FUNCTION {incollection}
   1497:FUNCTION {inproceedings}
   1532:FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }%% nach Patashnik, wg US-Kompatibilitaet
   1534:FUNCTION {manual}
   1587:FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
   1653:FUNCTION {misc}
   1787:FUNCTION {proceedings}
   1820:FUNCTION {techreport}
   1862:FUNCTION {unpublished} {misc}%%       AUTHOR, TITLE, NOTE muessen sein!
   1907:FUNCTION {sortify}
   2162:FUNCTION {presort}
```

But ignore the false matches for internal functions which leaves a list:

```
FUNCTION {article}
FUNCTION {book}
FUNCTION {booklet}
FUNCTION {inbook}
FUNCTION {incollection}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }%% nach Patashnik, wg US-Kompatibilitaet
FUNCTION {manual}
FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
FUNCTION {misc}
FUNCTION {proceedings}
FUNCTION {techreport}
FUNCTION {unpublished} {misc}%%       AUTHOR, TITLE, NOTE muessen sein!
```

Comment: However, for finding what are the required, optional and ignored field for each type one should look at the functions (and it's not very easy to tell).

Comment: @egreg Could you provide some details on this?

Comment: @Anna From the `article` function one can see that `author`, `title`, `crossref`, `lastchecked`, `doi`, `urn`, `issn`, `isbn` and `note` are either required or optional. But one has to examine other functions to be sure which is which.